# Spectrum of a weakly compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

It is well known that the power of a weakly compact operator is compact. Is the spectrum of a weakly compact operator is the same as a compact operator?

Comment: we know for a compact operator $K$, every nonzero $ λ \in \sigma(K)$ is an eigenvalue of $K$. Can I have the same property for a weakly compact operator?

Comment: I think he is asking if the spectrum of a weakly compact operator behave like the spectrum of a compact operator.

Comment: yes, I mean that Thomas says

Comment: Looking at the definition online, it looks like an operator is "weakly compact" when it maps the unit ball into a pre-weakly compact set. Now, if you take operators on a Hilbert space, then the weak and weak-$*$ topologies agree, so that the unit ball is weakly compact. This would imply that every bounded operator is weakly compact. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MartinArgerami you should post this as answer

Comment: Done. Thanks. ${ }$

Answer (score 2):

If you consider operators on a Hilbert space, then the weak and weak-∗ topologies agree, so that the unit ball is weakly compact. This implies that every bounded operator is weakly compact. In particular, any compact subset of $\mathbb C$ can be the spectrum of a weakly compact operator.